# Groovy runtime method interception

Tags: groovy, metaclass, interception, method-invocation

I'm playing with Groovy and I wonder, why doesn't this piece of code works?

```
package test

interface A {
    void myMethod()
}

class B implements A {
    void myMethod() {
        println "No catch"
    }
}

B.metaClass.myMethod = {
    println "Catch!"
}

(new B()).myMethod()
```

It prints out `No catch`, while I expect it to print `Catch!` instead.

Comment: Related [Groovy Meta Programming](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11892620/462015)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bug in Groovy, there is an open issue in JIRA: Cannot override methods via metaclass that are part of an interface implementation, [GROOVY-3493](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-3493).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rewriting B.metaClass.myMethod, try following:

```
 B.metaClass.invokeMethod = {String methodName, args ->
    println "Catch!"
 }
```

This [blog post](http://blog.bensmann.com/method-interception-and-synthesis-with-groovy) describes it quite well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround but it only applies to all classes and not specific instances.

metaclass modification BEFORE construction:

```
interface I {
    def doIt()
}

class T implements I {
    def doIt() { true }
}

I.metaClass.doIt = { -> false }
T t = new T()
assert !t.doIt()
```

metaclass modification AFTER construction:

```
interface I {
    def doIt()
}

class T implements I {
    def doIt() { true }
}

T t = new T()
// Removing either of the following two lines breaks this
I.metaClass.doIt = { -> false }
t.metaClass.doIt = { -> false }
assert !t.doIt()
```